# Is it possible with SQL Server 2008 to have a Partioned Tables with an Identity Column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, partitioning

I'm not thinking of using it for the partition function. 
I just want to know, if it is supported or not.

Don't tell me why it is not a good idea to use such columns on partitioned tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Read about it [here (Simple Talk)](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/partitioned-tables-in-sql-server-2005/), section "Identities in a partitioned table"

Comment: He doesn't tell, what happens when there is a primary key on the identity column and partitions are swapped.

Answer (score 5):

I would never tell you it is a not a good idea to use an IDENTITY column on a partitioned table.

Including an IDENTITY column in a partitioned table is supported.